# Get count of users in the room

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-api

I use Twilio API to create video chat.
First user created new room "DoctorID" and second user connected to this room.
How can I detect count of users in "DoctorID" room?

I need to place third user in the queue, if "DoctorID" room already has 2 users: doctor and client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [`Room` class](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.0.0-beta5/docs/Room.html) has a property of `participants` which is a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of Participant SIDs to Participants. You should be able to call on `room.participants.size` to find out how many participants are in the room.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Can I get room object without connection to this room?
If "DoctorID" room already has 2 users (doctor and first client), the second client should not be connected to their conversation.

Comment: You have a connection to the room with the doctor's account. You could implement this like so: if the doctor currently has a participant in the room with them then you can set a flag to say they are busy, when the person leaves you can then under that flag. Then you just need to check that flag and not connect anyone else to the room.

Comment: Can I get this flag via API, or I should send this flag on my server ?

Comment: You'd need to set it on your own server somewhere.

Comment: Of course, this might not be the best way to approach the problem at all. It might be better to create a room per patient and have the doctor join that room when it is time for the appointment, rather than having one room per doctor and keep people out of it.